# Get PHP class namespace dynamically

Tags: php, oop, introspection

How can I retrieve a class namespace automatically?

The magic var `__NAMESPACE__` is unreliable since in subclasses it's not correctly defined.

Example:

`class Foo\bar\A` -> `__NAMESPACE__` === Foo\bar

`class Ping\pong\B extends Foo\bar\A` -> `__NAMESPACE__` === Foo\bar (it should be Ping\pong)

ps: I noticed the same wrong behavior using `__CLASS__`, but I solved using `get_called_class()`... is there something like `get_called_class_namespace()`? How can I implement such function?

UPDATE:
I think the solution is in my own question, since I realized `get_called_class()` returns the fully qualified class name and thus I can extract the namespace from it :D
...Anyway if there is a more effective approach let me know ;)

Comment: Your solution is what I've had to do in personal code. http://codepad.viper-7.com/EgObtf

Comment: What you describe is not wrong behavior. See what those constants carry: http://php.net/language.constants.predefined - and as you've found a solution to your problem, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Check this one out. I think this is what you mean:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317343/get-child-class-namespace-from-superclass-in-php/20193599#20193599

Comment: I think this is what your're after:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317343/get-child-class-namespace-from-superclass-in-php/20193599#20193599

Answer (score 19):

The namespace of `class Foo\Bar\A` is `Foo\Bar`, so the `__NAMESPACE__` is working very well. What you are looking for is probably *namespaced classname* that you could easily get by joining `echo __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . __CLASS__;`.

Consider next example:

```
namespace Foo\Bar\FooBar;

use Ping\Pong\HongKong;

class A extends HongKong\B {

    function __construct() {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    }
}

new A;
```

Will print out `Foo\Bar\FooBar` which is very correct...

And even if you then do

```
namespace Ping\Pong\HongKong;

use Foo\Bar\FooBar;

class B extends FooBar\A {

    function __construct() {
        new A;
    }
}
```

it will echo `Foo\Bar\FooBar`, which again is very correct...

**EDIT:** If you need to get the namespace of the nested class within the main that is nesting it, simply use:

```
namespace Ping\Pong\HongKong;

use Foo\Bar\FooBar;

class B extends FooBar\A {

    function __construct() {
        $a = new A;
        echo $a_ns = substr(get_class($a), 0, strrpos(get_class($a), '\\'));
    }
}
```

Comment: They're using \_\_NAMESPACE\_\_ in the parent class, but they want the namespace of the child class.

Comment: @MaximilianRuta Well, thank You for Your edit, but please, in the future only correct what is necessary to be corrected. All occurrences of **You** changed to **you**? This is my style of writing and to show some politeness so if You do not mind, let me keep my style of expressing myself. Thanks! Also thank to reviewers for approving such **minor** and not so much **correct** edit request... Well done!

Comment: The problem is that i have to change at least n chars for an edit request. Thats the reason why i had to change something else in your post.

Comment: Why do You write like this?

Answer (score 14):

In PHP 5.5, ::class is available which makes things 10X easier. E.g.

`A::class`

Comment: Example http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-179

Comment: or `get_class()` for dynamic classes.

Answer (score 11):

Use [Reflection class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php).

```
$class_name = get_class($this);

$reflection_class = new \ReflectionClass($class_name);

$namespace = $reflection_class->getNamespaceName();
```