# How to check if a class belongs to a certain namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm wondering if PHP provides a native way to check whether a class (instance) belongs to a certain namespace or not.

It doesn't really matter but just for your understanding how I came up with this question:

Using ZF2, I've got an event handler for the `onDispatch` event. However, this handler is invoked for *every* dispatch of any controller of any module. Obviously, I only want to perform an action in this handler if a controller of *this* module is being dispatched.

So I wanted to check whether the Controller is inside my module's namespace or not.

Btw, I solved this temporarily using a string compare on the class name (`strpos($className, 'ModuleName\Controller') !== false`). I guess that using `substr()` or `strncmp()` or something like that performs better than `strpos()`, but it doesn't really matter in my case.

Thanks in advance!

// Edit: To be clear, I'm looking for something like:

```
// $foo is an instance of MyApp\Controller\Moo
is_in_namespace('MyApp\Controller', $foo); // true
```

or

```
// $foo is an instance of MyApp\Controller\Moo
get_namespace($foo) === 'MyApp\Controller'; // true
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Get child class namespace from superclass in PHP 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317343/get-child-class-namespace-from-superclass-in-php-5-3)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Can you please explain what my question has to do with the one linked by you?

Comment: Umm, it get's a namespace for a given class… Did you read it or judge it by the title? Seems applicable seeing how both the answers below are the same answers for that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/get_class) to obtain the class of the object, then you can use `strops()` on it to find out if it contains the namespace. There isn't an equivalent `get_namespace()` function.

Example:

```
function is_in_namespace($namespace, $object) {
    return strpos(get_class($object), $namespace . '\\') === 0;
}
```

```
function get_namespace($object) {
    $class = get_class($object);
    $pos = strrpos($class, '\\');
    return substr($class, 0, $pos);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm currently doing, thanks for your answer!

Comment: From PHP8, we are now able to use  [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) instead of `strpos === 0`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ReflectionClass have [getNamespaceName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php)():

```
(new \ReflectionClass($foo))->getNamespaceName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constant `__NAMESPACE__` to get the current namespace

```
namespace MyProject;

echo '"', __NAMESPACE__, '"'; // outputs "MyProject"
```

Comment: Hmm, this is pretty much the same as I did, except that you insert the namespace dynamically instead of writing it into the source code.

Comment: @DanielM This statement doesn't make much sense... It is within the source, isn't?

Comment: With a clearer example, this will be a better choice. The constant __NAMESPACE__ containst the name of the current namespace, so it will be easy to use strpos to find out if a class belongs to cetain namespace.