# How can I get the full namespace of a class without creating an instance of it?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have something like this:

```
use Just\Some\Namespace\ClassName;

class A
{
    public static function doStuff()
    {
        echo function_name(ClassName);
    }
}

A::doStuff();
```

What I want to see printed is this: `Just\Some\Namespace\ClassName`

The whole idea is that I want to get the full namespace of a class **without** creating an object of that class.

I searched online and the closest I've came to a solution is the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317343/995822). However, none of them is what I need.

I could use reflection like this:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Just\\Some\\Namespace\\ClassName');
echo $reflectionClass->getNamespaceName();
```

but I would have to specify the namespace in order to create `ReflectionClass`. If I already know it, I wouldn't need it anymore.

---

What can I replace `function_name` with in my code in order to get `Just\Some\Namespace\ClassName` ?

Comment: You can use Composer's autoloader to get the full namespace of a class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862377/2511355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__CLASS__`

> The class name. (Added in PHP 4.3.0) As of PHP 5 this constant returns
>   the class name as it was declared (case-sensitive). In PHP 4 its value
>   is always lowercased. The class name includes the namespace it was
>   declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar). Note that as of PHP 5.4 **CLASS** works
>   also in traits. When used in a trait method, **CLASS** is the name of
>   the class the trait is used in

like

```
echo __CLASS__; //   The class name.
```

Comment: This is a great compromise for those stuck with versions of PHP older than 5.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP5.5 you can use the [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) keyword for namespace resolution

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name
>   resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name
>   of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly
>   useful with namespaced classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use Just\Some\Namespace\ClassName;

class A
{
    public static function doStuff()
    {
        echo function_name(ClassName::class);
    }
}

A::doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get the class "basename" (without namespace) of the given object / class.

```
function class_basename($class)
{
    $class = is_object($class) ? get_class($class) : $class;

    return basename(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));
}
```