# What model will be returned when using relationship from extended model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider the following scenario:
Two models are extended from a package, the relationship between these models is defined in the package.
For example, a doctor and patients:

Doctor in App:

```
namespace App;

use SomePackage\Doctor as VendorDoctor

class Doctor extends VendorDoctor
{
    (...)
}
```

Patient in App:

```
namespace App;

use SomePackage\Patient as VendorPatient

class Patient extends VendorPatient
{
    (...)
}
```

Doctor in vendor package:

```
namespace SomePackage;

class Doctor extends Model
{
    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);
    }
}
```

Patient in vendor package:

```
namespace SomePackage;

class Patient extends Model
{
    public function doctor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class);
    }
}
```

Which model will be returned when I use the relationship?
Example:

```
$patient = \App\Patient::find($id);
$doctor = $patient->doctor;
```

Will `$doctor` be App\Doctor, with the functions available to that model, or SomePackage\Doctor?

Answer (score 1):

By default it will be `SomePackage\Doctor`. You could overrride the relationship though.

Comment: It is as I feared then. We have several projects connected to the same database (an API, an admin panel,...), so we opted to have a custom package with the models to share between the projects. But if the relationships have to be overridden anyway, it kind of beats the main purpose of having the package.

Answer (score 1):

By default it will return `SomePackage\Doctor`, because of that code in `SomePackage`:

```php
public function patients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);
    }
```

Here `Patient::class` is a special constant that contain full path (with namespace) to Patient class. It contain something like `SomePackage\Patient`, that path belongs to package itself. So, you can't change it only by using another Class with the same name.

But you can `redefine` the whole method inside your `App\Doctor` class.

```php
namespace App;

use SomePackage\Doctor as VendorDoctor

class Doctor extends VendorDoctor
{
    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Patient::class);
    }
}
```

After that `App\Doctor` will return relation with `App\Patient`.

```php
$doctor = \App\Doctor::find($id);
$patient = $doctor->patient;
//$patient containt Collection of App\Patient models
```

Actually you don't even need to define full `\App\Patient:class` path, because here you are already in `App` namespace, I just add it for better understanding.

Comment: It is as I feared then. We have several projects connected to the same database (an API, an admin panel,...), so we opted to have a custom package with the models to share between the projects. But if the relationships have to be overridden anyway, it kind of beats the main purpose of having the package.

Comment: Not really. Instead of using `return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);` you can get path to `Patient::class` from a method or constant. Like `self::getPatientPath()` or `self::patientClass`. So when you extend the `Model` you need only to override one property.

Comment: You can solve you task even dynamically, by playing with getting the right namespace. See more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317343/get-child-class-namespace-from-superclass-in-php

Comment: @MrEvers is that answer enough for you or there still something else?

Comment: It's something I'll definately have to look into in further detail.